# C# NetworkAvailabilitychangedEvent

Tags: c#, networking

VS 2008

I am developing an application that has to detect whether a client has a network connection. i.e. LAN cable plugged in or wireless switched on. I have been using the code below.

I am using the NetworkAvailabilitychangedEvent to fire an event when their wireless is turned off or the cable has been pulled out. However, this only works if the user has only 3 connections present (LAN, Wireless, and loopbacks).

Microsoft: "The network is available when at least one network interface is marked "up" and is not a tunnel or loopback interface".

However, some client has more than 3 connections. One client had a bluetooth connection and someone else had some VMWare connections. On these client it failed to fire the event.

Is there anyway I can ignore all these connections I am not interested in listening out for, and just listen on the LAN and Wireless?

Many thanks for any advice,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(OnNetworkChangedEvent);  
    }

    private void OnNetworkChangedEvent(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
    {
        bool available = e.IsAvailable;

        NetworkInterface[] networkConnections = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (NetworkInterface ni in networkConnections)
        {
            if (ni.Name == "Local Area Connection")
            {
                if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Down)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("LAN disconnected: " + ni.Description);
                }
            }
            else if (ni.Name == "Wireless Network Connection")
            {
                if (ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Down)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wireless disconnected: " + ni.Description);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The docs do not state that it works only if there are at most three network interfaces. So I doubt that it is a problem with the number of interfaces.

Comment: I understand the doc's. However, if you have say 5 network connections. For the event to trigger all of them have to be either connected or disconnected. For example, if 3 are connected and 2 are disconnected no event will fire. Another example, one of our clients has some VMWare connections. If they are enabled then it then it matters if the wireless or LAN get disconnected as the event will not fire. All of them have to be connected or disconnected for the event to fire. Currently I want to ignore all connections that are not wireless or LAN. My code I am only checking for wireless and LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to implement some sort of polling agent that runs on a seperate thread and regularly tries to contact something listening on a remote server (or servers?).

When it fails (or perhaps when a preset number of connection attempts fail) then fire an event. Same when it goes from a fail-succeed state.

Your application would subscribe to these events and take action accordingly.

Of course this may not be suitable for your scenario..

Comment: Hello, I am interested in what you have said. Do you know of any design pattern that implement this? Any articles? Thanks

Comment: No, I just came up with it.

It really wouldn't be that hard to implement from scratch...